# Puppeteer cant find selector on menu click

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

[image]

Hi, i would like to be able to click on system tools and then on the firmware upgrade button, but when i use the ID or the selector ( by right click -> copy selector), it jst says that it cant find it.

It's my first time using Puppeteer, can someone help please :) ?

Thanks

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

```
let scrape = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({width: 1000, height: 500})
  await page.goto('http://192.168.2.107:8080/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.waitFor('input[id=pcPassword]');
  await page.$eval('input[id=pcPassword]', el => el.value = 'admin');

   page.keyboard.press('Enter')
   await page.waitFor(3000);
  await page.click(
    '[id="the Id im talking about "]'
);
  //await page.waitFor(5000);
  await browser.close();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just had to select the frame, i didn't know that,

Here is the code :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async () => {
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'], headless:false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({width: 1900, height: 700})
  await page.goto('http://192.168.2.105:8080', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.waitFor('input[id=pcPassword]');
  await page.$eval('input[id=pcPassword]', el => el.value = 'admin');

   page.keyboard.press('Enter');
   await page.waitFor(3000);

 const frame = await page.frames().find(f => f.name() === 'bottomLeftFrame');
    const button = await frame.$('#menu_tools');
    button.click();
       await page.waitFor(1000);
    const button2 = await frame.$('#menu_softup');
    button2.click();
      }
scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // Success!
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comments to this answer I think that we are dealing with frames in the page. That's the reason why puppeteer is unable to find the element `#menu_tools` despite it being visible to you in the page. To access the frames in the page look more at [Puppeteer pageFrames](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageframes).

Here's a demo of how your code may look.

```
let scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: 1000, height: 500})
    await page.goto('http://192.168.2.107:8080/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    // Find out which frame holds your desired selector then edit the pageFrame below.
    const pageFrame = await page.mainFrame().childFrames[0];
    await pageFrame.waitFor('input[id=pcPassword]');
    await pageFrame.$eval('input[id=pcPassword]', el => el.value = 'admin');
    pageFrame.keyboard.press('Enter')
    await pageFrame.waitFor(3000);
    await pageFrame.waitFor('#menu_tools')
    await pageFrame.click('#menu_tools');
    await browser.close();
};
```

You can find all the frames available in the page with `await page.frames()` then connect to that frame. You can then proceed to perform operations like you usually do so with a page by using the handle for that frame.

Comment: I got (node:3532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: a#menu_tools.T.sel.minus
    at assert (C:\Users\hbalas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:251:11)
    at Frame.click (C:\Users\hbalas\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:591:5)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Comment: How can i give you more informations in order to help me ?

Comment: Try to upload the webpage as HTML in a website (say pastebin) You can use 'Save Page WE' a chrome browser extension to save the webpage as HTML

Comment: @StéphaneGuillemot edited my answer try again with the above one.

Comment: with the wait for selector i got :
Error: waiting for selector "#menu_tools" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

Comment: I am still stuck :/

Comment: @StéphaneGuillemot sorry, I could help if I could access the website but am unable to help you since I can't. I may have a TP Link router lying around. If I manage to find it I will try to help you out within today.

Comment: Here is the code i extracted from the website

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vwotxAP7TLvOEUFJ5cwib4A0ccd-E0M8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The ID seems to be fine so that isn't the issue. When you run your script are you able to properly see the website being loaded completely? Also try running the script again with this argument again: `await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'], headless:false})`

Comment: I got the exact same issue, the selector copied by google chrome is #menu_tools 

And it says : Error: waiting for selector "#menu_tools" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

And yes the web is completely loaded

Comment: maybe because the menu is in a Htm file in a framset

Comment: @StéphaneGuillemot I think your page works with frames. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I found myself and answered my topic, it was the frame ! 
Thanks for everything